# What's the reason for this no-op while-loop used for assert macro?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, while-loop, assert

I'm reviewing a codebase where `assert` macro is expanded like this in non-debug configurations:

```
#define assert( what ) while( 0 )( ( void )1 )
```

which I don't quite get. Obviously the goal is to have a no-op. Then why not expand into an empty string?

```
#define assert( what )
```

What's the reason for this no-op loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely to avoid compiler warnings. Check whether this code provokes a warning about an empty statement:

```
if (foo);
```

If it does, then do you want the same warning in release mode for the following code?

```
if (foo) assert(what);
```

C99 (which is relevant to C++11) also says that `assert` expands "to a void expression". IIRC, whitespace alone isn't an *expression*, even though whitespace followed by a semi-colon is an *expression-statement*. Good old BNF grammar.

By the way, this definition of `assert` is not standard-conforming. C89 and C99 both say that when `NDEBUG` is defined, then assert is defined as:

```
#define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
```

I'm not sure whether the authors consider it an important requirement, but a program could for example stringify the macro expansion and expect a particular result.

Answer (score 2):

To gobble up the semicolon, most likely. Whether it's needed or not — I don't think it'll make much difference, but at the same time, it doesn't hurt anything, either.