# Set global environment variable out of Node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, spawn, env

I am trying to set a global environment variable out of my node.js app.

The goals are:

1. When restarting the APP, the environment variable should still be set
2. When opening a new shell, it should be usable
3. If possible: When rebooting, same as 1.
4. It should work on Linux, Mac OS X (and needs an alternate SET command for windows)

Here is what I did:

```
var setEnv = require('child_process')
        .spawn('export GLOBALVARNAME='+my.value,{
          stdio: 'inherit',
          env: process.env
        });
```

But this causes in

```
{ [Error: spawn export GLOBALVARNAME=foobar ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn export GLOBALVARNAME=foobar',
  path: 'export GLOBALVARNAME=foobar',
  spawnargs: [] }
```

I didn't test this on Windows, but on Mac OS X (and Linux) the right command on bash is `export GLOBALVARNAME=value`. For Windows the right command should be `SET GLOBALVARNAME=value` - isn't it ?

So the main question is: Whats going wrong with the manual working `export GLOBALVARNAME=foobar` ?

Comment: to understand why it is giving you `ENOENT` check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have pointed out, shelling out and changing an environment variable is basically a [NO-OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978620/whats-a-portable-way-to-implement-no-op-statement-in-c).  Either you want to change the environment for your current process and its children or you want to change it for new processes.  Editing `/etc/profile` will make the change for any new processes as @Hmlth says.

If you want to change the environment for your current process this is straight forward:

```
process.env.YOUR_VAR = 'your_value';
```

Answer (score 3):

`export` is not a standalone command but a shell builtin that sets the environment variable for the current shell process and its children forked after it is set.

You can't set an environment variable for processes that are not descendants of the current process. And under Linux, there is no such thing as system environment variable.

Under Linux, your variable should be set in the init script that spawns your app or in the systemd unit. If you want it to be available in interactive user shells, it should be set in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d`

.

Comment: I thought it is a standalone command ... that is bad. So I need to open a file and write into it. Damn...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js shows how to access your environment without shelling out.  It works for writes too.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs**

I don't think it is possible for a child process to change the parent's process environment. So I don't really think it is possible to use `child_process`.

Sample code:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec('export ENV_VARIABLE=ABRACADABRA');
```

Comment: you are right, it doesn't work using child_process. Thought export makes things global with the effect it is not relevant what is the parent shell...

Comment: It wont work in windows also. The main aim for shelljs is mutiplatform